# Does SQL SERVER supports FIRST_ROWS feature like oracle does?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, odbc, query-optimization, ado

We known that Oracle support a optimizer mode called **FIRST_ROWS** ，I want known whether SQL Server has some thing like this. Meaning `what should I do if I want to get the first row of a select statement as soon as possible while not waiting it to complete`. If it has, can I use it in database drivers like ODBC and may be ADO components?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it does. You can use the FAST query hint, which gives you the first x rows of a query as fast as possible, to achieve this. Have a look at this example code:

```
SELECT        whatever
FROM          YourTable
OPTION (FAST 1)
```

You can also use the FASTFIRSTROW table hint:

```
SELECT        whatever
FROM          YourTable
WITH (FASTFIRSTROW)
```

Comment: @Maximilian: Thanks. Do you know can I use this with ODBC or ADO components?

Comment: So what's the basis difefrence between Fast and TOP? Any link will be really appreciated..

Comment: @chenwq: I'm sure you can. @SQL: TOP limits the number of rows returned by a query. When you say TOP 10, that means 'only give me 10 rows'. When you say FAST 10, that means 'give me all the rows this query returns, but give me the first 10 as fast as you possibly can, even if that means the query will perform worse overall'.

Comment: any msdn link...will be really helpful. +1 for Fast.

Comment: and what's the use of this feature in database driven application ?

Comment: Link for TOP: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189463.aspx
Link for FAST an other query hints: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Like [TOP 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) ?

There is also optimizer hint: `FAST number_rows`. ([Query Hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx))

> Specifies that the query is optimized
>   for fast retrieval of the first
>   number_rows. This is a nonnegative
>   integer. After the first number_rows
>   are returned, the query continues
>   execution and produces its full result
>   set.

Comment: Thanks. actually my original question is when I use ADO dataset I cannot open it as quickly as possible. When I use server side cursor, **ADO use sp_cursoropen/sp_cursorfetch instead of query hints** , I just tested use query hints with dataset, and it does not work.